# Some questions about the class "func" in Swift language?

Tags: swift, class

For the last line, why shouldn't it be:

```
greet(name: "Bob", day: "Tuesday")
```

Anyone have some idea?

```
func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
}

greet("Bob", day: "Tuesday")
```

Comment: just declare like this: func greet(name name: String, day: String) -> String {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“By default, the first parameter omits its external name, and the second and subsequent parameters use their local name as their external name.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.0).”, Section **Function Parameter Names**

Apple recommends this so that code is concise and readable. Usually the function name includes an indication what the first parameter is. However if you really want to force the use of an external parameter name, specify both an external and local parameter label like this.

```
func greet(name name: String, day: String) -> String {
  return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
}
```

[image]

Comment: And the reason they do it this way is because it maps naturally to Objective-C naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Each parameter in a function has two names, the outsider name and the insider name.

The outsider name is the one that will be used when your function will be called.
The insider name is the one that you can call inside your function.

Your function :

```
func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
}
```

can be called like:

```
greet("Bob", day: "Tuesday")
```

You don't need to put the outside name for the first parameter because that is not necessary by swift. while it is necessary to put it for the other parameters (rather than the first one)

you can force your function to be called with outside name parameter even for the first parameter like this:

```
func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
        return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
    }
```

then your call would be:

```
 greet(name: "Bob", day: "Tuesday")
```

Another example:

```
func testtest(outside1 inside1: String, outside2 inside2: String) {
    print("inside1 = \(inside1)") // okay
    print("inside2 = \(inside2)") // okay
    print("outside1 = \(outside1)") // ERROR outside1 doesn't exist
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
testtest(outside1: "wow", outside2: "meoao")
```